# REST parent id in URI

Tags: java, rest, uri

Let's say my model consists of a `Parent` entity that refers some `Child` entities, via `children` property. The path segment of the URI of a specific `Child`, according to REST principles, would be `/parent/{parentId}/children/{childId}`.

When performing update operations on a `Child`, usually `childId` is all I need in order to uniquely identify the correct `Child`, deeming the `parentId` segment in the path redundant. This redundancy aggravates as the hierarchy grows complex.

Now that I think of it, it may also cause unexpected behavior: accessing URIs with the same `childId` but with **different** `parentId` could result in the same behavior, if the programmer isn't aware. What should probably happen when accessing a `Child` under an unrelated `Parent` is that a client error code should be returned.

Currently I think that maybe no hierarchy should be introduced to REST API unless it is absolutely intuitive, as it:

1. Makes the URI - thus the API - more complex. Hardens maintainability.
2. The redundancy may cause users to reason about the outcome of accessing some URIs.
3. The redundancy may become a pitfall to the unaware programmer.

**Is there a way to evade this redundancy and still conform REST principles?**

Comment: REST is a set of principles, not a standard.

Comment: What is an “outcome” of a URI? (Someone using an API _of any kind_ wants to be able to predict the outcome of an operation, at least to a basic level.)

Comment: @DonalFellows - outcome of accessing the URIs. I edited the question for you :). The problem is that this kind of API isn't predictable enough.

Comment: REST has no opinion on the structure of the URI so you are trying to conform to something that does not exist.  Check the dissertation http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm.  This "RESTFul URL" concept is something made up by framework writers to pretend that they are helping people do REST.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, just structure your URL like this...

`/children/{childId}`

Since you can infer the parent from the child on the server side, there is no reason to declare it in the URL.  You should only put multiple resources in a URL when you absolutely need to.  For example, a user voting on a comment.  Since there is no formal way to determine on the database side, you would create a url like..

`/voter/{userId}/comment/{commentId}/upvote`

Comment: so what you're saying is that my observation is correct, right? Is there any reference link you can add? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, your observation that the url structure you've shown is redundant is correct.  But to be honest I don't know of a good reference from the top of my head.  If someone else finds a good article/reference which explains in more detail or cites specs/etc then upvote/accept their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since REST is referring to Resources, they don't necessarily have to be hierarchical.

In a similar API, I have Sections, Categories, and Articles.  Each of these is, of course, under one of the other, but in REST I specify them as section/{id} & article/{id}.  They're still links to individual resources - but since they CAN be independent of their parent, the hierarchy isn't important to specify in the URI.

If you definitely want to specify the hierarchy in the URI, you should check to make sure the parent is the parent of the child, and throw an error elsewise - in order to maintain hierarchical integrity.

TL;DR

- /parent/{parentID}
- /child/{childID}

Comment: It seems like Dave and you say somewhat the same so I'll ask you the same questions: is my observation correct, then? Is there any reference link you can add? Thanks.

Comment: It is a little redundant, and I don't think you'll be able to find a true reference link.  REST after all is a methodology.

Consider it this way: OOP.  You have Objects.  Sometimes they're only relevant in relation to their parent, other times they're relevant all by themselves.  The latter is what you'd reflect in the structure I gave.

Answer (score 1):

for me this question answer is going to be driven by data modeling, and for data modeling the question is "using composite key for child model or not" if he is using composite key so you have to put the parent id in URI if not and child have its own id which is not composite so you can just use URL with child id only.

so this is data modeling question!!!